# Selector first-child, first-of-type not working

Tags: html, css

I have tried both first-child and first-of-type to hidden a first class "entry-list" but not working.

Here my code :

HTML

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="view-more"></div>
    <div class="entry-list"></div>
    <div class="entry-list"></div>
    <div class="entry-list"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.entry-content>.row>div.entry-list:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the `.view-more` div, and then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your element  in your `.view-more` class you can do it by using `first-of-type`

```css
.row div:first-of-type {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <span class="view-more">VM</span>
    <div class="entry-list">1</div>
    <div class="entry-list">2</div>
    <div class="entry-list">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get this done if you wrap your entry lists div with a another div.

You can read more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="view-more"></div>
    <div class="entry-lists">
        <div class="entry-list">First</div>
        <div class="entry-list">Second</div>
        <div class="entry-list">Last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h92dfz3o/